# Django QuerySet lazy evaluation different in python debugger compared to normal execution

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm working on implementing a paging solution for running post-processing on a model that has grown very large in the database.

The general approach I'm taking for this is the following:

1. set up the base QuerySet definition
2. evaluate the total row count using .count() (i.e. not returning all of the data yet)
3. use the QuerySet slicing syntax to fetch the data in chunks with a bounded size

The pseudo code looks something like the following:

```
1 : base_queryset = MyBigModel.objects.filter(...).values(...).exclude(...).annotate(...).order_by(...)
2 :
3 : count = base_queryset.count()
4 : 
5 : chunks = (count // pagesize) + 1
6 : for i in list(range(chunks)):
7 :    # grab slice of queryset
8 :    chunk_qs = base_queryset[(i * pagesize):(i * pagesize) + pagesize]
9 :    print(chunk_qs.query)      # examine rendered SQL
10:    print(chunk_qs.explain())  # examine query plan
```

When I run the above code in normal mode it behaves as expected. The QuerySet slicing syntax on line 8 returns another QuerySet object and I'm able to inspect the SQL query and query plan on lines 9-10. Note that my expectation is even at this point, the query has not been fully executed. The lazy evaluation should hold off until I perform an operation that forces evaluation as per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated.

However, when I step through this code in the python debugger, I find the base QuerySet object has already been evaluated after line 1. As a consequence of that, the slice operator on line 8 no longer returns a QuerySet object. It instead returns a Python list of dictionaries with the table data contained within it.

This presents two issues:

1. Lines 9-10 throw exceptions in debug mode since Python list objects don't have .query or .explain() attributes.
2. The bigger issue, is that query evaluation on line 1 has no size bounds on it (i.e. LIMIT/OFFSET are unbounded) which means the full QuerySet is evaluated which can lead to memory exhaustion with the volume of data coming back.

My intent is to withhold the evaluation of the query until I get into the slicing loop but I don't know how to forcefully suppress Django from evaluating it until I get into the slice loop even from the python debugger environment.

Any tips for this?

Comment: That is because the debugger calls `__str__` on the object, to present in the list of variables, and the `__str__` will evaluate the object.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  Thanks for the explanation. Do you know of any clever work-arounds to avoid this? As I said, my primary concern is having it hit the DB with the unbounded query in the first place. The rest I can manage around.